# How can I copy a file from a remote server to using Putty in Windows?

Tags: windows, putty, pscp

How do I copy a file from a remote server to my local Windows system using a Putty session?

Comment: One solution is to configure port forwarding with putty (e.g. 8080 to 8080), then inside your SSH session run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080`. Then locally open a browser and go to `localhost:8080`.

Answer (score 168, accepted):

It worked using PSCP.
Instructions:

1. Download PSCP.EXE from Putty [download](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html) page
2. Open command prompt and type `set PATH=<path to the pscp.exe file>`
3. In command prompt point to the location of the pscp.exe using cd command
4. Type `pscp`
5. use the following command to copy file form remote server to the local system

   ```
   pscp [options] [user@]host:source target
   ```

So to copy the file `/etc/hosts` from the server `example.com` as user `fred` to the file
`c:\temp\example-hosts.txt`, you would type:

```
pscp fred@example.com:/etc/hosts c:\temp\example-hosts.txt
```

Comment: if you need to connect to a specific port then use the following.

pscp -P <port> userid@:path/source_file_name c:\path\destination

Comment: To authenticate with ssh key use `-i C:\path\id_rsa.ppk`  [link](https://verrytechnical.com/using-pscp-with-ssh-key-pair-authentication-to-transfer-files/)

Comment: It is handy to save the session in putty and use that session so no hassle of authentication within pscp. `pscp sessionname:source target` , where sessionname is replaced by the name of your saved session in putty.

Comment: So it's not possible to do this inside the putty window, it has to be used in CMD?

Comment: @HermanToothrot it seems like it. you need to run it separately from putty. Also, i think i should point out that you need double-quotes on the Windows path if you specify a full path like this: `pscp pi@192.168.0.123:/folder/myfile.txt "D:\Temporary\\myfile.txt"`


alternatively, you could always use WinSCP which is way easier to use because of the GUI

Comment: What's the point of obliterating your `PATH` settings if you're just going to `cd` into `pscp`'s folder anyway? Why even include step 4 (which does nothing)? These instructions are mess.

Answer (score 97):

One of the putty tools is pscp.exe; it will allow you to copy files from your remote host.