# copy file from Windows to UNIX using PUTTY

Tags: unix, putty

I need to copy a file from windows to UNIX to a specific folder and set the file group (chgrp or something).
The problem is that i have more than 16 groups in unix.

Is there a way to do it without writing and launching a UNIX script?

Comment: You have to use `pscp` instead.

Answer (score 4):

It should work using PSCP. Instructions:

1. Download PSCP.EXE from Putty download page
2. Open command prompt and type `set PATH=<path to the pscp.exe file>`
3. In command prompt point to the location of the `pscp.exe` using `cd` command
4. Type `pscp`
5. use the following command to copy file form remote server to the local system

   `pscp [options] [user@]host:source target`

So to copy the file `/etc/hosts` from the server `example.com` as user fred to the file `c:\temp\example-hosts.txt`, you would type:

```
pscp fred@example.com:/etc/hosts c:\temp\example-hosts.txt
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217055/how-can-i-copy-file-from-putty-to-windows)

Answer (score 0):

The above answer by @Ravi Dhoriya is good but sometimes it does not work.  You might need to add the -scp flag to force the scp protocol:

```
pscp -scp fred@example.com:/etc/hosts c:\temp\example-hosts.txt
```