# Is there any easy way to copy files from Unix server to Windows?

Tags: unix

Actually I have 80k files coming into my Unix Box every half hr. I wanted a efficient way to copy the files to Windows in a lesser time.

Comment: Ever heard of scp, sftp and rsync? By the way, the question belongs to http://unix.stackexchange.com/ or to http://superuser.com/

Comment: Refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23308092/copy-file-from-unix-to-windows-using-putty

Answer (score 0):

```
scp -r /file_in_unix/ user@windows_hostname:/cygdrive/c/
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Zulu i know this method. This Site content some notes. http://www.it.cornell.edu/services/managed_servers/howto/file_transfer/fileunixserver.cfm